# How to add Bar Code in EuroPass CV

Tags: pdftex, europecv

I want to add barcode in EuroPass CV mentioning application number just after photo. Now, I can do that using minipage, but, it actually push text downward.

Here is my latex code:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,openbib,nologo,notitle,noflag,totpages]{europecv}                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage{graphicx}                
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}                
\usepackage[english]{babel}                
\usepackage{url}                
\usepackage{makebarcode}                


\ecvname{Doe, Joe}                
\ecvfootername{Joe Doe}                
\ecvaddress{Nowhere in London, England, UK}                
\ecvtelephone{12345678}                
\ecvfax{12345678}                
\ecvemail{\url{email@address.com}}                
\ecvnationality{English}                
\ecvdateofbirth{Dec 24 1990}                
\ecvgender{male}                
\ecvbeforepicture{                
\raggedleft                
}                
\ecvpicture[height=3cm]{lion.png}                
\ecvafterpicture{                
\tabularnewline                
\begin{minipage}{19.5cm}                
\flushright                
\fbox{                
\barcode[code=2/5-Industrial]{012345678912}                
}                
\end{minipage}                
\ecvspace{-3.5cm}                
}                
\ecvfootnote{Some Footnote}                

\begin{document}                
\selectlanguage{english}                

\begin{europecv}                
\ecvpersonalinfo[5pt]                

\ecvsection{Work experience}                

\ecvitem{Date}{2010 -- 2013}                
\ecvitem{Occupation or position held}{CV writer, Very Big Company}                

\ecvsection{Education and training}                

\ecvitem{Place and Date}{Very Big University, 2008 -- 2010}                
\ecvitem[10pt]{Title of qualification awarded}{MSc in Nothinglogy}                

\ecvitem{Place and Date}{Big University, 2005 -- 2008}                
\ecvitem{Title of qualification awarded}{BSc in Nothinglogy}                


\ecvsection{Personal skills and~competences}                

\ecvmothertongue[5pt]{English}                
\ecvitem{\large Other language(s)}{French, German}                
\ecvlanguageheader{(*)}                
\ecvlanguage{French}{good}{good}{good}{good}{good}                
\ecvlanguage{German}{good}{good}{good}{good}{good}                
\ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]{(*)}                

\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Social skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}                
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Organisational skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}                
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Technical skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}                
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Computer skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}                
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Artistic skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}                
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Other skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}                
\ecvitem{\large Driving licence(s)}{State here whether you hold a driving licence and if so for which categories of vehicle. (Remove if not relevant).}                

\ecvsection{Additional information}                
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{Include here any other information that may be relevant, for example contact persons, references, etc. (Remove heading if not relevant).}                

\ecvitem{}{\textbf{Personal interests}}                
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{Musics, Movies, Golf}                

\ecvitem{}{\textbf{References}}                
\ecvitem{}{Person One, Person Two}                

\end{europecv}                


\end{document}
```

I haven't changed the style class. I am attaching what currently the cv look like.[image]

There is a empty space above Personal Information, which is created after I added minipage. How to remove that. If you have any alternate way to do this, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add these lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\ecv@picture}{%
\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0.65\height]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]